# Mysql 4.0 Get data of Min value

Tags: mysql, group-by, min

is possible obtain records of the min id and  grouped by a column?  (in 4.0)

```
SELECT period, activity, date
FROM (
    SELECT MIN(id) id
    FROM Booking 
    WHERE place = 'CONFERENCE'          
    AND Date = '05 - Mar'   
    GROUP BY period
) A
INNER JOIN Booking B
USING (id) ORDER BY id
```

is possible equivalent to version 4.0?

Comment: Version 4.0 is 11 years old. You should really update.

Comment: Perhaps FORTRAN would be better suited to this task.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following gets the min of the id without a subquery:

```
select b1.period, b1.activity, b1.date
from booking b1 cross join
     booking b2
group by b1.id, b2.period
having b1.id = min(b2.id)
```

You can apply your `where` conditions as:

```
select b1.period, b1.activity, b1.date
from booking b1 cross join
     booking b2
where b2.place = 'CONFERENCE' and   
      b2.Date = '05 - Mar'   
group by b1.id, b2.period
having b1.id = min(b2.id);
```

Comment: How can `id` be unknown in the `having` clause if it is present in the `booking` table?